# Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to load two model in tensorflow ,but I get this error all the time, it seems 
I can only load one model in one code,The error is here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "X:/fffan/NLP/Classify/TextMix/pred_back.py", line 92, in <module>
textrcnn = TextRCNN_pred(vocab_dir="../data/cnews_vocab.txt")
File "X:/fffan/NLP/Classify/TextMix/pred_back.py", line 54, in __init__
saver.restore(sess=self.session, save_path=model_path)
File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\saver.py", line 1302, in restore err, "a Variable name or other graph key that is missing")
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Restoring from checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original error:

2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Not found: Key W_projection_cnn not found in checkpoint
  [[node save_1/RestoreV2 (defined at X:/fffan/NLP/Classify/TextMix/pred_back.py:46) ]]
  (1) Not found: Key W_projection_cnn not found in checkpoint
  [[node save_1/RestoreV2 (defined at X:/fffan/NLP/Classify/TextMix/pred_back.py:46) ]]
 [[save_1/RestoreV2/_57]]
 0 successful operations.
 0 derived errors ignored.

 Original stack trace for 'save_1/RestoreV2':
    File "X:/fffan/NLP/Classify/TextMix/pred_back.py", line 92, in <module>
textrcnn = TextRCNN_pred(vocab_dir="../data/cnews_vocab.txt")
    File "X:/fffan/NLP/Classify/TextMix/pred_back.py", line 46, in __init__
saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

And my code is here:

```
class Textcnn_pred(object):
    def __init__(self,vocab_dir):
        self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, config.seq_length], name='input_x')
        self.words = tools.read_file(vocab_dir)
        self.vocab_size = len(self.words)

        self.textcnn = TextCNN(config,self.vocab_size,keep_prob = 1.0)
        self.logits_cnn = self.textcnn.cnn(self.input_x)

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)

        sess_config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
        sess_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        with tf.Session() as self.sess:
            self.sess = tf.Session(config=sess_config)
        model_path = 'checkpoints/TextCNN/TextCNNnet_2019-11-01-15-31-50.ckpt-4000'
        saver.restore(sess=self.sess, save_path=model_path)
        print("################ load TextCNN model down! ##########################")

    def _close(self):
        self.sess.close()

    def text(self,input):
        logit_cnn = self.sess.run([self.logits_cnn], feed_dict={self.input_x:input})

        return logit_cnn
class TextRCNN_pred(object):
    def __init__(self,vocab_dir):
        self.input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, config.seq_length], name='input_x')
        self.words = tools.read_file(vocab_dir)
        self.vocab_size = len(self.words)

        self.textrcnn = TRCM.TextRCNN(config,self.vocab_size, 1.0)
        self.logits_rcnn = self.textrcnn.RCNN_inference(self.input_x)

        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True)

        sess_config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.4
        sess_config.gpu_options.allow_growth = True
        with tf.Session() as self.session:
            self.session = tf.Session(config=sess_config)
        model_path = 'checkpoints/TextRCNN/TextRCNNnet_2019-11-05-17-04-36.ckpt-7500'
        saver.restore(sess=self.session, save_path=model_path)
        print("################ load TextRCNN model down! ##########################")

    def _close(self):
        self.session.close()

    def text(self,input):
        logit_rcnn = self.session.run([self.logits_rcnn], feed_dict={self.input_x:input})
        return logit_rcnn
if __name__ == '__main__':
    one_text = ['sentence_1','sentence_2']
    ### encode those 2 sentence
    test_X = encode_sentence(one_data=one_text, vocab_data="../data/cnews_vocab.txt",max_length=config.seq_length)

    textcnn = Textcnn_pred(vocab_dir="../data/cnews_vocab.txt")
    logit_CNN = textcnn.text(test_X)

    textrcnn = TextRCNN_pred(vocab_dir="../data/cnews_vocab.txt")
    logit_RCNN = textrcnn.text(test_X)

    logit = logit_CNN + logit_RCNN
```

PS: Each of model is ok when I run them alone. Such as I run the code "logit_RCNN = textrcnn.text(test_X)" only, or run "logit_CNN = textcnn.text(test_X)" only, it is ok.

Does someone tell me how to debug this code? Thank you!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you figure it out?

Comment: I got it. For anyone looking, use tf.reset_default_graph()